# Random data generator applet returns `0x6F00`

Tags: javacard

I wrote the below program to generate random numbers of different lengths, using two different algorithms (`ALG_SECURE_RANDOM` and `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM`).

`P1` and `P2` in the APDU command specify the algorithm and the random length in order.

- `P1 = 0X01` : ALG_SECURE_RANDOM
- `P1 = 0X02` : ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM
- `P2` = Random number length

  public class RandGen extends Applet {

  ```
  byte[] generatedArray;
  byte[] generatedRandom;

  RandomData randomDataSecure = RandomData
          .getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
  RandomData randomDataPseudo = RandomData
          .getInstance(RandomData.ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM);

  private RandGen() {
  }

  public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
          throws ISOException {
      new RandGen().register();
  }

  public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {

      if (selectingApplet()) {
          return;
      }

      byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

      generatedArray = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(
              (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2], JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

      switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
      case (0x01):
          generatedRandom = secureRandomGenerator(apdu);
          break;

      case (0x02):
          generatedRandom = pseudoRandomGenerator(apdu);
          break;

      default:
          return;
      }

      Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
              (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_P2);
      apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_P2);
  }

  public byte[] secureRandomGenerator(APDU apdu) {
      byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
      randomDataSecure.generateData(generatedArray, (short) 0,
              (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
      return generatedArray;
  }

  public byte[] pseudoRandomGenerator(APDU apdu) {
      byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
      randomDataPseudo.generateData(generatedArray, (short) 0,
              (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
      return generatedArray;
  }
  ```

  }

The CAP file generated and uploaded on the card successfully, but when I send APDU commands to the card, I receive the `0X6F00` status word :

```
OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000202
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 02 02
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)

OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000102
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 01 02
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)
```

Is there something wrong in my applet?

---

**Update:**

Based on dear @Vojta's answer, I replace

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
        (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_P2);
apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_P2);
```

With following lines in `process()` method :

```
    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
            (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
```

Now I have a weird output in *OpenSC-Tool* output :

Secure random generator :

```
OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000110
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 01 10
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
B8 1F 80 25 A2 8E 25 30 F8 22 F8 40 0F AE B0 6C ...%..%0.".@...l
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00                                  .....

OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000110
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 01 10
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)

OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000110
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 01 10
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
F6 45 A9 0C 0C 3B 3A 5A 5F DC A8 36 .E...;:Z_..6
```

Pseudo random generator :

```
OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000210
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 02 10
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
37 FD FC 67 EB 9E 21 00 6B E9 44 A7 21 3F 31 9A 7..g..!.k.D.!?1.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            .......

OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000210
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 02 10
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)

OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000210
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 02 10
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
72 FE 48 1B 9A A0 BD 2D DF F9 E7 F8 58 CF B7 C0 r.H....-....X...
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                ...........
```

Why I have different output for a single command?

Comment: Note that the meaning of `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` and `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM` is subject of debate. Better consult your user manual what is actually returned. Oh, and don't instantiate objects, not even transient byte arrays, within the process method (unless it is part of personalization).

Comment: _not even transient byte arrays, within the process method_ **Why?** +++ _... unless it is part of personalization_ **For personalization we instantiate objects in process method? Why?**

Comment: Because your card will run out of resources (EEPROM or RAM). The garbage collector is not as reliable as in real Java. If you really, really need to instantiate objects in process method, use additional flag so that the creation is only done once.

Comment: @David do you mean that The card doesn't reclaim the space of transient objects after deselection or reset? I was thought that the memory (both EEPROM and RAM) space of this kind of objects (I mean the transient ones), will reclaim automatically without even calling `requestObjectDeletion()` method after deselection or reset (based on the type of object)! Am I wrong?

Comment: It may, and may not. It depends on the implementation of the card vendor. It is better to be cautious and follow the best practice to avoid problem in the future.

Comment: @David You are right, It is better to be cautious and follow the best practice to avoid problem in the future; but If the memory doesn't reclaimed for this kind of objects randomly, what the difference between transient objects and non-transient objects? (I mean, is not it mandatory (i.e. a standard that must be followed by vendors) to build the card in way that the space reclaims in this situations always?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little bug in your code. You want

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
            (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
```

instead of

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
            (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_P2);
```

General rule: ALWAYS surround the content of your `process` method with a try-catch block and set status words according to the type and reason of the exception. Otherwise you get only `6F00` and you do not know what really happened. If you followed this rule, you would know that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` was thrown.

**Answer to update:**

Weird output is caused by the fact, that

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
            (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]);
```

overwrites the `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]` with some random value and then this value is used on the next line. You should store `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]` in RAM in the beginning of the `process` method:

```
final byte p2 = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2];
```

**Answer to comment below:**

You have troubles for P2 >= 0x80, because of casting `byte` to `short`. Unfortunately, JavaCard handles byte as signed, that is why your length for P2 >= 0x80 is negative. You could easily avoid this by:

```
final short outputLen = (short) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Maybe that's a but, but that may not be the only one: `generatedRandom` is never instantiated.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes generatedRandom is just a pointer to generatedArray... Do not ask me why.

Comment: @vojta I think Mr. Bodewes's comment is correct. May I ask you why `generatedRandom` is a pointer to `generatedArray`? Thank you.

Comment: @Abraham
Because of line:
`generatedRandom = secureRandomGenerator(apdu);`

and because of the fact that the `secureRandomGenerator` method returns `generatedArray`. The same thing with `pseudoRandomGenerator`.

Comment: Oh God! you are right! Thanks. :) BTW, is there any limitation for the length of random data (i.e. value of `P2`)? It works fine for `P2 <= 0x79`, but for `P2 >= 0x80`, I receive `0X6F00` again.

Answer (score 0):

**command not supported**
You have the wrong instruction joining together.